# trying to redirect after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have a complicated situation with trying to make the login.aspx to redirect you to the web form you were at before the login. I am using ASP.NET/C# to program my web application. It sounds easy to do, but I am running into all sorts of issues doing this and I tried doing this many different ways. Here is the part of the login.aspx.cs that shows the redirect:

```
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    try{
        int start = url.IndexOf('=');
        if(url.Length > 0)
        {
            url = url.Substring(start, url.Length - 1 - start);
            url = url.Replace("=","");
        }
        Response.Redirect(url, false);
    }
    catch(Exception i)
    {}
```

The code above takes the url string and extracts the redirectURL variable (the address of the previous webform) and uses it for redirecting you after your login.
There is no exception within this try-catch, but the exception happens after the login tries to redirect to the previous web form. Here is a web form with directing login code:

```
    var returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
    Response.Redirect("~/Account/login.aspx?ReturnURL=" + returnUrl);
```

The problem is I get an SQL exception in the browser? I am not even using SQL during this redirect. here is what the exception says:

```
   [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred           while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not     accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to    allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating   Server/Instance Specified)]
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5066458
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire,   Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +341
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +5080107
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +31
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +76
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
    System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user,  String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +82

   [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +137
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +94
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +27
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +395
```

also the source error:

```
    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web
    request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be
    identified using the exception stack trace below (edit: above actually).
```

My guess is that for some reason the redirect is not finding the web form. I did try the returnURL variable string starting with and without a ~ to see if that worked and it didn't. I have also tried session variables and cookies... still didn't want to work. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like you are using a SQL backed user store. And it can't connect to the server - nothing to do with redirecting the response. how are you handling user authentication?

Comment: yea everything works just fine. I try to do a lookup program on the page that checks for your login and the SQL works just fine. authentication is also all good.

Comment: maybe somehow the SQL server is getting dis-connected from the website when the redirect happens? it only happens when the redirect command is executed...